# Equivalent of s:property in Spring MVC

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, jsp, struts2

I'm currently converting a Struts2 project to Spring MVC and I'm struggling finding the equivalent of the s:property tag in Spring.
Here is some example of what I want to convert:

```
<s:property value="#contentha.idcontent"/>
<s:property value="%{topRex.idcontent}"/>
```

Thanks for your help !

Comment: are you still going to use jsp or template engine such as thymeleaf ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can write

```jsp
${contentha.idcontent}
${topRew.idcontent}
```

If you want to use a tag you can write :

```jsp
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>

<c:out value="${contentha.idcontent}" />
<c:out value="${topRew.idcontent}" default="Value if null" />
```

This will require the `jstl` dependency. For example if you use Maven :

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>jstl</groupId>
    <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
    <version>1.2</version>
</dependency>
```